# Do university staff (in the US) usually have access to the university resources needed to do research?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, job, irb

Naturally, no one expects university staff (administrative or otherwise) to carry out research, but it was recently suggested to me that having such a job gives you access to the university resources you would need to do research if you so wish. This person was, I think, referring to library access, but might this include journal access and even IRB access? If so, is this access commonly found in universities in the US or is it somewhat atypical?

Comment: Journals are part of library access, no?

Comment: @JonCuster Often but not always.

Comment: "Naturally, no one expects University staff to carry our research". Wait, what?

Comment: @penelope, by staff they are likely referring to any non-academic worker at the university.

Comment: @penelope Exactly what bbq said: At least at the universities I've been to, "staff" refers to non-academics and "faculty" refers to academics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Library access would include access to journal articles that the library subscribes to. Yes, I'd expect anyone working for a US university to have that access.

As far as everything else, my experience is that this falls under "PI status" (a given institution may have a different name). If your university grants you "PI status", you're allowed to apply for grants on behalf of the university and with that comes access to all the university research administration. Tenure-track faculty are all going to have PI status; for anyone else it's an administrative process. I would not expect, say, HR staff to have any possibility of PI status. A non-faculty research position might, though. Some positions that are nominally research support positions might be able to direct their own research, too.

For anyone else, access to these sorts of resources is going to be through someone who *does* have these powers, and of course is up to your "boss".

Comment: Yeah, I would say research support positions (librarians, technicians for analysis/instrument platforms, or glassblowers even) conducting research or publishing semi-independently is relatively common. Educators (teaching-only faculties, lab coordinators) also have their own discipline.

Comment: Thank's for this insight. At my current university (where I'm a PhD candidate), I used to be able to submit research plans to the IRB myself, but they have more recently decided that students can't be PIs and therefore need their advisors to sign off as the PIs even if those advisors have no involvement in the project at all. I wouldn't surprise me to find the same arrangement for university staff if they decided to do research.

Comment: I should note that even among faculty, some things limited to "PIs" may not be available. At my US R1 university it has come to my attention that some non-tenure-track faculty (full time faculty whose contractual workload is just teaching and service) are forbidden from applying for research grants, using certain resources, or otherwise representing themselves as a researcher at the university. I suspect that, like joshisanonymous's experience as a PhD student, these faculty would also be unable to self-submit IRB proposals.

Comment: @commscho I had tenure-track faculty in mind so I've modified that.